# Magento 1.6 Custom options not updating price

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

Magento site is not updating the price according to the custom option added.

I have narrowed it down due to the custom theme, although I have basically copied and totally changed the blank theme. I have compared themes, view.phtml, price, etc and cannot see any issues with anything being missed out.

I have checked each theme to which javascript files each theme is calling, and have ensured they are all the same JS files,

the function - custom options are all calling onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" which is the norm, but how can I trace this error? no errors are coming up within debug or within code inspector!

Also searched numerous forums, and here - similar but no resolutions...so hopefully if we can figure this out it will help others with the same problem.

Comment: Have you compared the layout xml files as well?

Comment: Thanks Sean, any idea which layouts? Ihave checked catalog.xml, page.xml and few others, compared and seem to be the same. Should I copy all default to the theme view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, in the template I was removing the top price in the view.phtml and magento is obviously setup to have it placed there, to work with the functions to update the price.

Sounds obvious, but there is two price boxes, one at top and one at bottom, I removed the top price variable/div instead of hiding it with css.

Hidden with CSS and Wallah, its updating the price once again and working as it should.

Answer (score 2):

For change custom option value, you should change in to js/varient/product.js

and in that page you found, reload:function()

that function call at the time of on change event.

Good Luck